# Intersection of $N$ hypersurfaces in the hypercube $[0,1]^N$

Tags: general-topology

For an application in optimization, I came across the following problem:

(Notation: Let $[0,1]^N$ denote a real hypercube. For a vector $t\in [0,1]^N$, let $\hat{t}_i\in [0,1]^{N-1}$ denote the removal of the $i$-th coordinate.)

Let $g_i:[0,1]^{N-1}\to [0,1]$ be continuous functions and define hypersurfaces
\begin{align}
    S_i:=\{t\in [0,1]^N: t_i=g_i(\hat{t}_i)\}.
\end{align}

Is the intersection
\begin{align}
    S_1\cap \cdots \cap S_N
\end{align}
necessarily non-empty?

This is a generalized version of [intersection of continuous curves in a square.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2429172/intersection-of-continuous-curves-in-a-square), where the answer is ''yes''.

For my application, it is not a restriction to assume that $g_i$ are smooth.

Comment: @RobArthan, in this case the sets $\{(t_1,c_1):t_1\in [0,1]\}$ and $\{(c_2,t_2):t_2\in [0,1]\}$ are straight lines in the square $[0,1]^2$. Two such straight lines clearly meet in a point.

Comment: @Carlyle: If we put $N=2$, then we get a square $[0,1]^2$. Our two hypersurfaces $S_1,S_2$ are curves in this square (they are graphs defined by equations $t_2=g_2(t_1),t_1=g_1(t_2) $ for some continuous $g_1,g_2$. For instance, $S_1=\{(g_1(t_2),t_2): t_2\in [0,1]\}$). $S_1$ is a continuous curve meeting the lower and top edges of the square, and $S_2$ is a continuous curve meeting the left and right edges of the square (or the other way around.) Does this clarify?

Comment: @Cellardoor, yes thank you, an interesting question

Comment: Makes sense now. I'll delete my comments.